# error: CLASS_NAME has not been declared/does not name a type (c++)

Tags: c++

I don't know why I'm getting this error, because it compiled perfectly just an hour ago and I haven't made any change here.

I have a class called SocketsStatus, and then I have many threads which implement a socket connection each one. So I'm passing a reference to a SocketsStatus object to control which ones are connected and which ones not.

Header of SocketsStatus:

```
#ifndef SOCKETSSTATUS_H_
#define SOCKETSSTATUS_H_

#include <QMutex>
#include <BufferDatos.h>

class SocketsStatus {
public:
    SocketsStatus();
    int setBufferStatus(int bufferId, bool status);
    bool isEveryBufferDisconnected();
    virtual ~SocketsStatus();

private:
    void init();

    bool bufferRawMeasConnected;
    bool bufferPosConnected;
    bool bufferRtkConnected;
    QMutex *mutex;
};

#endif /* SOCKETSSTATUS_H_ */
```

Then, beginning of header of BufferDatos, which is my Thread class:

```
#ifndef BUFFERDATOS_H_
#define BUFFERDATOS_H_

#include <QThread>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <SocketsStatus.h>
#include "Global.h"

class BufferDatos: public QThread {
public:
    BufferDatos(QString ip, qint16 port, SocketsStatus &buffersStatusPassed);
    virtual QByteArray extraerSiguienteMensaje(void) = 0;
    virtual ~BufferDatos();

protected:
    void run(void);
    bool connect(void);
    void receiveData(void);
    bool reconnect(int &timeoutsWithOpenSocket);

protected:
    QTcpSocket *tcpSocket;
    QString ip;
    qint16 port;
    SocketsStatus &buffersStatus;
//...
```

I'm getting **error: ‘SocketsStatus’ has not been declared** at the ctr, and then when declaring the variable as protected I also get **error: ‘SocketsStatus’ does not name a type**.

Must be some stupid detail, but I don't happen to see where! Any help?

Comment: possible duplicate of ['Scanner' does not name a type error in g++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706040/scanner-does-not-name-a-type-error-in-g)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an `#include` cyclic dependency. Each of your header tries to include the other one. Does `SocketsStatus` really need to know about `BufferDatos`? You need to remove one of the two `#include`s, you may replace one of them with a forward declaration.

Comment: I always thought that using **#ifndef SOCKETSSTATUS_H_
#define SOCKETSSTATUS_H_ #endif** prevented cyclic dependency to happen. Isn't that its purpose @K-ballo ?

Comment: @Roman Rdgz: Their purpose is to prevent including a header twice within a translation unit. While they prevent the compiler from including your headers ad infinitum, one still has to be included first and at that point the symbols from the other header aren't yet defined.

Answer (score 1):

break your cyclic `#include` dependency (by omitting one of the `#include` directives) and replace it with a (or few) forward declarations.

In fact, I don't think you need to `#include <Bufferdatos.h>` in the first header.